# what does it mean that "not proportional"?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) article.

And here it says, "Let r(t) be a curve in Euclidean space, representing the position vector of the particle as a function of time. The Frenet–Serret formulas apply to curves which are non-degenerate, which roughly means that they have nonzero curvature. More formally, in this situation the velocity vector r′(t) and the acceleration vector r′′(t) are required not to be proportional."

What does it mean that "not proportional" at the end of the sentence?

Does this mean that $r'(t)$ and $r''(t)$ are nonzero ?

Comment: In this context, proportional = colinear (hence being nonzero is unrelated, consider the vectors (1,0) and (0,1), say).

Comment: It is meant that the two vectors $r'(t)$ and $r''(t)$ should be linearly independent.